# Match a process' prompts and respond programmatically

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm writing a script to auto-update all my SSH auto-login keys locally. The following script is run if one of my computers doesn't have the initial SSH files yet (and I'm also thinking of sharing it on GitHub after some testing);

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

.. and so I get prompts;

- Enter file in which to save the key (/Users/allendar/.ssh/id_rsa):
- Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
- Enter same passphrase again:

The same goes for dynamically adding all the passkeys in the `ssh-copy-id` command.

I'm mainly only using `os` libraries now, but I read online I should use something like `subprocess` `Popen`.

Is there a way I can catch each prompt I get from that subprocess and maybe match their questions with Regex or literal string matching, and based on that I could send the process a response.

So if I would open a subprocess `ssh-keygen -t rsa` and it asks `Enter same passphrase again:` I could maybe catch (read) what it asks and send back a response `ComplexPassword`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) instead.

```
import pexpect

kg = pexpect.spawn('ssh-keygen -t rsa')
kg.expect('Enter same passphrase again:')
```

Comment: Thank you Martijn, works great. Does the `expect` read the inserted string as regex by default or just wilcards like `.*`?

Comment: Expect takes a string or a regular expression. See the [generated documentation](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html).

Comment: To be precise, it will take strings or compiled regex objects, and it will compile strings into regexes.

Comment: Here's a tryout; https://github.com/Allendar/ssh_batch_updater_auto_login. I never used GitHub for my own checkouts before (used Mercurial mainly internally), so might not be very pretty yet.